# JPA Eclipselink error inserting into table

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink, persistence

So first a bit of back story. The issue I am having is when I create a user. Previously I had tried to create a user and assign them a role separately before discovering that by inserting into the SEC_USER_ROLE table the program was also inserting into the APP_USER table and I was getting an error about inserting duplicate values into the parent table. However, now by creating the user and role together I am getting the following error:

> Primary key should be primitive (or list of primitives for composite
>   pk) , an instance of java.lang.Long with the primary keys filled in or
>   an instance of WebIntSecRole.......

Code as follows, not sure where I'm goin g wrong or the best solution at this point.

Admin.java:

```
            //New User Creation
    WebIntUser newUser = new WebIntUser();
    newUser.setLoginId(newLoginName);
    newUser.setCreatedBy(loggedUser);
    newUser.setCreatedOn(today);
    newUser.setDbAuth(true);
    newUser.setDeleted(false);
    newUser.setDisabled(false);
    newUser.setEmail(newEmail);
    newUser.setEncrypted(true);
    newUser.setEncryptPassword(true);
    newUser.setFirstName(newFirstName);
    newUser.setLastName(newLastName);
    newUser.setUpdatedBy(loggedUser);
    newUser.setUpdatedOn(today);
    newUser.setVersion(1);
    newUser.setLdapId(1);
    //userService.createUser(newUser);

    //Set role for new user
    WebIntSecRoleUser newUserRole = new WebIntSecRoleUser();
    newUserRole.setUser(newUser);
    newUserRole.setDeleted(false);
    newUserRole.setRole(userService.selectRoleById(1));
    //newUserRole.setCreatedBy(loggedUser);
    //newUserRole.setCreatedOn(today);
    //newUserRole.setUpdatedBy(loggedUser);
    //newUserRole.setUpdatedOn(today);
    newUserRole.setVersionNumber(0);
    userService.createRole(newUserRole);
```

WebIntUser.java

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "APP_USER")
@EntityListeners(value = { AuditChangeListener.class })
public class WebIntUser implements Serializable {
public WebIntUser() {
};

public WebIntUser(String login, String pass) {
    this.loginId = login;
    this.password = pass;
}

private Integer userId;
private String loginId;
private String password;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private boolean disabled;
private boolean deleted;
private boolean dbAuth;
private boolean isEncrypted;
private boolean encryptPassword;
private Date lastLogin;
private Date prevLogin;
private Integer version;
private Date lastPasswordChange;
private Date createdOn;
private Date updatedOn;
private String createdBy;
private String updatedBy;
private Integer ldapId;

public static interface propertyName {
    String userId = "userId";
    String loginId = "loginId";
    String password = "password";
    String firstName = "firstName";
    String lastName = "lastName";
    String email = "email";
    String disabled = "disabled";
    String deleted = "deleted";
    String dbAuth = "dbAuth";
    String isEncrypted = "isEncrypted";
    String encryptPassword = "encryptPassword";
    String lastLogin = "lastLogin";
    String prevLogin = "prevLogin";
    String version = "version";
    String lastPasswordChange = "lastPasswordChange";
    String createdOn = "createdOn";
    String updatedOn = "updatedOn";
    String createdBy = "createdBy";
    String updatedBy = "updatedBy";
    String ldapId = "ldapId";
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
public Integer getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
.....getters/setters
}
```

WebIntSecRoleUser.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SEC_ROLE_USER")
@EntityListeners(value = {AuditInfoChangeListener.class})
public class WebIntSecRoleUser implements AuditableDomainObject {

private Long id;
private WebIntSecRole role;
private WebIntUser user;
private boolean deleted;
private AuditInfo auditInfo;
private long versionNumber;
private Date createdOn;
private Date updatedOn;
private String createdBy;
private String updatedBy;

public interface propertyName extends Auditable.propertyName {
    String id="id";
    String role="role";
    String user="user";
    String deleted = "deleted";
    String createdOn = "createdOn";
    String updatedOn = "updatedOn";
    String createdBy = "createdBy";
    String updatedBy = "updatedBy";
}

public static interface permissionKey{
   String UPDATE="SecRoleUser.U";
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ROLE_USER_ID",nullable = false, unique = true)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID", nullable=false)
public WebIntSecRole getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(WebIntSecRole role) {
    this.role = role;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", nullable = false)
public WebIntUser getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(WebIntUser user) {
    this.user = user;
}
Getters/setters
}
```

Note: There is some commented out code that I'm either trying not to use anymore, or in the case of Created By and Created On etc I was getting errors for multiple inserts.

Comment: Can you show more of the exception, such as the stack trace?  I don't see how setting Created by and created On could possibly cause multiple inserts, so there is more going on to this code.  I'm going to guess the problem is with your userService.selectRoleById(1) method call somehow, as the exception does not seem related to JPA or the entities you've shown- it is like something is trying to lookup a WebIntSecRole but doesn't understand the value given to it.

Comment: I got this to work by changing the Id of WebIntSecRole to Integer from Long. (selectRoleById was returning null) Thanks to all for pointing me in the right direction, the smallest thing had derailed my progress. MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you have missed the @ManyToOne mapping on the `WebIntSecRole`. You only specified the @JoinColumn.

```
@ManyToOne(/* desired options */)
@JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID", nullable=false)
public WebIntSecRole getRole() {
    return role;
```

Comment: This is true, albeit I'm still running into the error

Comment: Are you sure .. userService.selectRoleById(1).. this does not return a null?